# WPF - How to center column data in ListView?

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, alignment

I'm still learning WPF, but I'm really confused about something that should be really simple.  What I want to do is to center the contents of the 3rd and 4th columns.  When I run this, the columns are left justified:

```
<ListView Margin="0" x:Name="listMonitoredUrls" AlternationCount="1"
          ItemsSource="{Binding}"  >
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Description" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FriendlyDesc}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Url" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Url}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Frequency">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ScanFrequencyMinutes}"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Next Scan"  >
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TimeNextScanStr}"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

I"m really starting to like WPF, but some simple things like this seem to be really hard.

Comment: sorry it's a bit late for my answer, however, I met same problem and solved it by appending my dedicated width size in the element under DataTemplate, i.e., in your case, <DataTemplate><TextBlock .. Width="{Binding ElementName=[REF], Path=ActualWidth}"></DataTemplate/>, which will adjust content width in accordance with your binding [REF] element. Ever did try neither 'HorizontalAlignment'  nor 'HorizonalTextAligent' work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `TextAlignment` property instead of `HorizontalAlignment` - should do it. 
To my understanding `HorizontalAlignment="Center"` will center your textblock not the text in it.

Comment: That was what I used in my first attempt.  It doesn't work either.  Sorry for not putting that in my initial posting.

Comment: does it work if you aling left or right? check this link and see if you can spot differences with your xaml --> http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/1f17a5a6-c71f-4810-b8bc-e4eb2a25fa96/

Answer (score 0):

This might be a long shot but i've had to do it for listboxes where the items are defined by templates. Try setting the HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" on your ListView. If I don't set that the items take only as much space as they need and are left justified.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a solution which works under the common scenario of:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Some Property" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding SomeProperty}" />
```

where one only wants a simple `DisplayMemberBinding` with text without having to specify a `CellTemplate`

the new code uses an attached property and becomes:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Some Property" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding SomeProperty}" 
                ctrl:GridViewExtensions.IsContentCentered="True" />
```

attached property code:

```
public static class GridViewExtensions
{
    #region IsContentCentered

    [Category("Common")]
    [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(GridViewColumn))]
    public static bool GetIsContentCentered(GridViewColumn gridViewColumn)
    {
        return (bool)gridViewColumn.GetValue(IsContentCenteredProperty);
    }
    public static void SetIsContentCentered(GridViewColumn gridViewColumn, bool value)
    {
        gridViewColumn.SetValue(IsContentCenteredProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsContentCenteredProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "IsContentCentered",
            typeof(bool), // type
            typeof(GridViewExtensions), // containing type
            new PropertyMetadata(default(bool), OnIsContentCenteredChanged)
            );

    private static void OnIsContentCenteredChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnIsContentCenteredChanged((GridViewColumn)d, (bool)e.NewValue);
    }
    private static void OnIsContentCenteredChanged(GridViewColumn gridViewColumn, bool isContentCentered)
    {
        if (isContentCentered == false) { return; }
        // must wait a bit otherwise GridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding will not yet be initialized, 
        new DispatcherTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100), DispatcherPriority.Normal, OnColumnLoaded, gridViewColumn.Dispatcher)
        {
            Tag = gridViewColumn
        }.Start();
    }

    static void OnColumnLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var timer = (DispatcherTimer)sender;
        timer.Stop();

        var gridViewColumn = (GridViewColumn)timer.Tag;
        if (gridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Only allowed with DisplayMemberBinding.");
        }
        var textBlockFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
        textBlockFactory.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, gridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding);
        textBlockFactory.SetValue(TextBlock.TextAlignmentProperty, TextAlignment.Center);
        var cellTemplate = new DataTemplate { VisualTree = textBlockFactory };
        gridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding = null; // must null, otherwise CellTemplate won't be recognized
        gridViewColumn.CellTemplate = cellTemplate;
    }

    #endregion IsContentCentered
```

}

Comment: note that i did NOT thoroughly test the `DispatcherTimer` interval, so you may want to mess with it.

Comment: also, note that my solution does NOT take into count a changing to the value. (i.e. if the `IsContentCentered` value is changed from true to false, the binding will not revert to left-alignment)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my example to show a working xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_Tutorial.Rich_text_controls.BlockUIContainerCenteredColumnSample"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:self="clr-namespace:WPF_Tutorial.Rich_text_controls"
        Title="BlockUIContainerCenteredColumnSample" Height="275" Width="300"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Window.Resources>
        <x:Array x:Key="UserArray" Type="{x:Type self:User}">
            <self:User Name="John Doe" Age="42" />
            <self:User Name="Jane May-Anne Josephine Renalds Doe" Age="36" />
        </x:Array>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
            <FlowDocument>
                <Paragraph FontSize="36" Margin="0">Users</Paragraph>
                <Paragraph FontStyle="Italic" TextAlignment="Left" FontSize="14" Foreground="Gray">Here's a list of our users, inside our FlowDocument, in a completely interactive ListView control!</Paragraph>
                <BlockUIContainer>
                    <ListView BorderThickness="0" ItemsSource="{StaticResource UserArray}" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                <!-- This stretches out the TextBlock width to the column width -->
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                            </Style>
                        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <ListView.View>
                            <GridView>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Width="150" />
                                <GridViewColumn>
                                    <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Age" Width="75" />
                                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}" TextAlignment="Center" />
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn>
                            </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                    </ListView>
                </BlockUIContainer>
                <Paragraph FontStyle="Italic" TextAlignment="Left" FontSize="14" Foreground="Gray">More content can go here...</Paragraph>
            </FlowDocument>
        </FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Notice the `<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>` block.  It has the `<Setter ...`.
Without this, as per AndyG's text, nothing will work the way you want.

This has been very frustrating trying to work out.

By the way, here is the backing-code for this xaml:

```
namespace WPF_Tutorial.Rich_text_controls
{
    using System.Windows;

    public partial class BlockUIContainerCenteredColumnSample : Window
    {
        public BlockUIContainerCenteredColumnSample()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

    public class User
    {
        public int Age { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[What you should see when run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tu3dq.png)